# Eevee contact shadows VS model complexity

Tags: subdivision-surface, shadows

I have contact shadows and ambient occlusion working well to represent position and height of buildings model on top of a terrain object, in a top-down, orthographic view.

The terrain object has a subdivision modifier; when the Simple Subdivision is at 8:

- CON: details of the terrain are insufficient
- PRO: shadows are clean

When the Simple Subdivision is at 10:

- PRO: details of the terrain are adequate
- CON: shadows are jagged

Isn't there a way for me to get the best of both worlds?

Render with subdivision at 8:
[image: Terrain Simple Subdivision at 8]

Render with subdivision at 10:
[image: Terrain Simple Subdivision at 10]

Comment: Sorry, but with a basic setup I cannot recreate this behaviour. I can only get better or worse results from the shadow settings, but not the subdivisions. This must be dependent on your terrain so it may be best to upload your file here: https://blend-exchange.com and edit it into your question.

Comment: I can't. For this to work the terrain displace map must be embedded, but blend-exchange won't take files over 30MB. Looking for an alternative, will return.

Comment: Here: https://enacshare.epfl.ch/fFoq92MkzhusjaGDW7eUgvpQxH3cw4Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the subdivision on its own. You have a *Displacement* modifier on the ground object, with more subdivisions i.e. higher resolution, more details in the displacement appear which the settings of your *Contact Shadows* cannot handle.

Your object is quite small, try setting the *Bias* (of the *Contact Shadows*, not the regular *Shadow's Bias* directly above) to something a lot smaller, e.g. 0.001 instead of the 0.01 you have there. The shadows will look much better:

[image: contact shadows bias]

Comment: Excellent. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much!

I used to dabble quite a lot in 3DS Max back in the day, now I only return to 3D software occasionally when I have specific needs, and that can be hell because you forget everything from one session to the next...

Comment: How do I rep you?

Comment: To the left of the answer you will find a checkmark to accept the answer as solution. By the way, if you are using _Cycles_ as a render engine, these settings are not necessary and the shadows will automatically be correct - and corresponding in direction and length to the angle of the sun. After switching to _Cycles_ you can see that your shadows are much too short, you need to set the _Distance_ to at least 20 mm to get the full length. And the lower the sun's angle will be, the longer the distance needs to be - if you want them accurate.

Comment: Right. Thanks again. A+ help there.